# What is the difference between QProcess::start and QProcess::startDetached?

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

The Qt documentation gives this explanation:

- `QProcess::start`:

  > Starts the given program in a new process, if none is already running,
  >   passing the command line arguments in arguments.
- `QProcess::startDetached`:

  > Starts the program program with the arguments arguments in a new
  >   process, and detaches from it.

What is the difference between the two? Is the difference only that you can start just one instance of a program using `QProcess::start` and many instances using `QProcess::startDetached`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you use `start`, termination of the caller process will cause the termination of the called process as well. If you use `startDetached`, after the caller is terminated, the child will continue to live. For example:

```
QProcess * p = new QProcess();
p->start("some-app");
delete p;// <---some-app will be terminated

QProcess * p = new QProcess();
p->startDetached("some-app");
delete p;// <---some-app will continue to live
```

Comment: what if some-app run some other child processes, is the termination will terminate them in case of start()?

Answer (score 5):

The start() function is a member function, while startDetached is a static class function.

If you look at the [documentation of QProcess](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QProcess.html), you'll see that there are functions to allow you to do things with the process such as: -

- Receive the output or error streams from the running process ([readAllStandardOutput](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html#readAllStandardOutput) / [readAllStandardError](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html#readAllStandardError))
- Redirect the output to a file ([setStandardOutputFile](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html#setStandardOutputFile))
- Use a file for standard input into the process ([setStandardInputFile](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html#setStandardInputFile))
- [Communicate via channels](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QProcess.html#communicating-via-channels)
- Get [notified when the process has finished](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html#finished)

These are just some of the things that you can only do with an instance of a QProcess. If, however, you want a simple and quick way of starting a process without having to create an instance and you don't need the extra functionality, you can simply call QProcess::startDetached.

Also, as the docs state for [startDetached](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached): -

> If the calling process exits, the detached process will continue to live.

Comment: While it is true that startDetached() is static, QProcess:execute() is static, too, if you just wish to run a program without an instance. I think the real difference is the detachment.

Comment: So, how to kill `startDetached`?

Comment: @Sigur Send a kill signal to the process. e.g: kill -KILL <pid>