# python parallel processes return exit code

Tags: python, subprocess

lets see if I can make this clear... I'm a total Python beginner so bear with me, this is my first python program (though I'm familiar with basic scripting in a few other languages). I've been searching around for hours and I'm sure the answer to this is fairly simple but I have yet to get it to work properly.

I'm writing a code that should launch multiple commandline processes, and when each one finishes I want to update a cell in a QTableWidget. The table has a row for each process to run, and each row has a cell for the "status" of the process.

I can run this no problem if I just do a for loop, spawning one process per row using `subprocess.call()` however this is too linear and I would like to fire them all off at the same time and not hang the program for each loop cycle. I've been digging through the subprocess documentation and am having a really hard time with it. I understand that I need to use `subprocess.Popen` (which will prevent my program from hanging while the process runs, and thus I can spawn multiple instances). Where I run into trouble is getting the exit code back so that I can update my table, without hanging the program - for instance using `subprocess.wait()` followed by a `subprocess.returncode` still just sticks until the process completes. I need a sort of "when process completes, check the exit code and run a function that updates the QTableWidget."

I did find these two posts that seemed to get me going in the right direction, but didn't quite get me there:

[Understanding Popen.communicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768290/understanding-popen-communicate)

[How to get exit code when using Python subprocess communicate method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631624/how-to-get-exit-code-when-using-python-subprocess-communicate-method)

Hopefully that made sense. Here's a simplified version of my code, I realize it is half-baked and half-broken but I've been screwing around with it for over an hour and I've lost track of a few things...

```
import os, subprocess

ae_app = 'afterfx'
ae_path = os.path.join('C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe After Effects CC 2015/Support Files', ae_app + ".exe")
filename = "E:/Programming/Python/Archive tool/talk.jsx"
commandLine = 'afterfx -noui -r ' + filename

processList = [commandLine]
processes = []

for process in processList:
    f = os.tmpfile()
    aeProcess = subprocess.Popen(process, executable=ae_path, stdout=f)
    processes.append((aeProcess, f))

for aeProcess, f in processes:
    # this is where I need serious help...
    aeProcess.wait()
    print "the line is:"
    print aeProcess.returncode
```

- Spencer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned PyQt, so you can use PyQt's [QProcess](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qprocess.html) class.

```
def start_processes(self, process_list):
    for cmd, args in process_list:
        proc = QProcess(self)
        proc.finished.connect(self.process_finished)
        proc.start(cmd, args)

def process_finished(self, code, status):
    # Do something
```

**UPDATE:** Added fully working example. Works properly for both PyQt4 and PyQt5 (to switch just comment line 3 and uncomment line 4)

sleeper.py

```
import sys
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime as dt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = int(sys.argv[1])
    started = dt.now().time()
    sleep(x)
    ended = dt.now().time()
    print('Slept for: {}, started: {}, ended: {}'.format(x, started, ended))
    sys.exit(0)
```

main.py

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
# from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui as QtWidgets


class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    cmd = r'python.exe C:\_work\test\sleeper.py {}'

    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 500, 300)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Start processes', self)
        self.button.move(20, 20)
        self.editor = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)
        self.editor.setGeometry(20, 60, 460, 200)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.start_proc)

    def start_proc(self):
        for x in range(5):
            proc = QtCore.QProcess(self)
            proc.finished.connect(self.finished)
            proc.start(self.cmd.format(x))

    def finished(self, code, status):
        self.editor.append(str(self.sender().readAllStandardOutput()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = App()
    gui.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know that existed in PyQt! I'm running into an error but I think it's because I'm using QProcess incorrectly. In the codumentation looks like it takes 2 arguments: "cmd" and "args" which is how I see you have process_list set up. So I guess my question is this - can you take it back one step further and show me how you would set up "process_list"? Is it supposed to be a tuple or something? Right now it just contains a string for each command, the string being the commandline text

Comment: process_list = (('some.exe', '--some_params'), ('another.exe','-p 10 -r 20'))

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, were almost there! The args list actually has to be a QStringArray, which I have working no problem. What I'm running into now is that one of the args is a filepath with spaces in it, and for some reason that isn't passing to the process properly (it doesn't respond to it). From the documenatation: _Arguments that contain spaces are wrapped in quotes._ so I assume this is where my problem lies, because I was running the subprocess without quotes fine. Interestingly if I type it in cmd with quotes it works fine... Not sure what to do next!

Comment: Hah, figured out a workaround! In looking back at the documentation I realized you don't need to supply the arguments in a separate array, you can smash them right in there with the _program_ argument and that prevents pyqt from messing with your strings!

Comment: Aaarg! Well I got everything running with QProcess but now my `process_finished` function is not running. According to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24148477/using-qprocess-finished-in-python-3-and-pyqt) you can not get a finihsed signal from `QProcess.startDetached()`! So I think this is the wrong direction... Back to subprocess?

Comment: Oops, my bad. You should use `start()` instead of `startDetached()`, as latter is a static function and doesn't create object. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298060/do-i-get-a-finished-slot-if-a-start-qprocess-using-startdetached) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263805/what-is-the-difference-between-qprocessstart-and-qprocessstartdetached) for more information.

Comment: Yes that's exactly right, however that just brings me right back to my original question because now I can not run this in parallel, python has to wait for each process to complete before starting the next...

Comment: Just created test project and everything works in parallel. I'll update post with text code.

Comment: Yup, finally got it all working! Thanks much, this has been quite a learning experience and I was able to code a totally different tool just now using this as well :)